# Searching for a value in an array, and storing it if it doesn't exist

Tags: java, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

I am looking to input an integer between 10 and 100 into a one dimensional array, and if the value already exists anywhere in the array, do not insert it into the array, but notify user and resume input until 5 unique numbers are added.

Here is my code.  I know it's not right, but you can see that what I am trying to do is use simple for loops and a search method to get the numbers, store them into the array and search for a duplicate. My problem in my code is that I can't seem to set the number I just entered as the variable 'key' which I need to send to the method 'search'.

```
// input an integer between 10 and 100, add to array and print results. if value is already in array, notify user, print array. keep adding to array until 5 unique values have been entered

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] list = new int[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter number: ");
            list[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        int count = search(list, key);
        System.out.println("It has been entered.");
    }

    public static int search(int[] list, int key) {

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i].equals(key)) {
                ;
            }
            count++;
        }
        return (count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple example with array. Could improve with alternate data structure list set.

The search() method is essentially included within the while() loop, namely the for() loop examples the search for a target number already being included.

`int c = 0;` is declared before the loops and makes sure to find 5 unique numbers.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] list = new int[5];
        int c = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        while (c < 5 && s.hasNext()) {
            int n = s.nextInt();
            boolean has = n >= 10 && n <= 100;
            for (int i = 0; i <= c && !has; ++i)
                if (list[i] == n)
                    has = true;
            if (!has) {
                System.out.println("It has been entered.");
                list[c++] = n;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Result = " + Arrays.toString(list));
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Alternate version:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class ArraySearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(5);
        int c = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        while (c < 5 && s.hasNext()) {
            int n = s.nextInt();
            if ((n < 10) || (n > 100) || !set.add(n))
                continue;
            else {
                System.out.println("It has been entered.");
                c++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Result = " + set);
        s.close();
    }
}
```

additionally, using `search()`

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] list = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter number: ");
            int n = s.nextInt();
            if ((n >= 10 && n <= 100) && search(list, n) == 0) {
                list[i] = n;
                System.out.println("It has been entered.");
            } else
                i--;
        }
        System.out.println("Result = " + Arrays.toString(list));
        s.close();
    }

    public static int search(int[] list, int key) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i] == key) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Edit: also added the 10-100 spec

edit2: using your approach with search() method

Comment: Thank you, some of it is a bit above my head but I believe I can work through these and therein lies the answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any questions feel free to ask too. Note: in the 3rd block of example code (using the search method) the `i--;` is used to reset/deincrement the `i` int variable by 1 in order to keep the for-loop going until 5 numbers are used. If the `i--;` wasn't used when a number isn't entered then the for-loop would stop after 5 iterations no matter what (e.g. wouldn't correctly get 5 numbers entered but program would stop looking)

Comment: Which is exactly where I went wrong. I was working on the code today and was able to punch it out, thanks for the help. I kept incrementing the counter instead of decinrementing it.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the input directly in the array.
Save the input in a temporal variable which you'll pass to `search`. And based on result of `search` you add to the array or prompt for another input.

```
int[] list = new int[5];

for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    int temp = input.nextInt();
    if(search(list,temp) == 0)
        list[i] = temp;
    }else{
        System.out.println("It has been entered.");
        i--;
    }
}
```